# CSWinRT Path '16.1' is not a file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime

I'm trying to do Generate a C# projection from a C++/WinRT component, I'm getting the following error when trying to compile:

```
2>EXEC : error : Path '16.1' is not a file or directory
2>C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.cswinrt\2.0.3\build\Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT.targets(191,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.cswinrt\2.0.3\cswinrt.exe" @"C:\Users\user\solution\project\obj\Debug\net7.0-ios\Generated Files\cswinrt.rsp"" exited with code 1.
```

What could be the reason? The only 16.1 comes from net7.0-ios16.1.

Comment: Difficult to say w/o a single piece of a bit of reproducing project. You can use procmon tool from sysinternals (filter on file file) to check what files/directories are being accessed.